# Cucumber defined steps, at runtime stated as undefined

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber-java

- As part of self-learning, I have created a simple selenium cucumber project (java).
- I have created the feature file for a contactUs scenario and also defined & implemented the respective steps.
- There are no undefined steps for the mentioned scenario.

The feature file

```
Feature: Submit data to webdriveruniversity.com using contact us form

  

    Scenario: Submit valid data via contact us form
        Given I access webdriveruniversity contact us form
        When I enter a valid first name
        | tiger | micheal | Indiana |
        When I enter a valid last name
        | woods | jackson | jones   |
        And I enter a valid email address
        And I enter comments
        | example comment 1 | example comment 2|
        When I click on the submit button
        Then The information should be successfully submitted via contact us form
```

The associated step file

```
package stepDefinitions;

import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.junit.Assert;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class contactUsSteps {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Before()
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toRealPath() + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\other\\chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @After()
    public void tearDown(){
        this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        this.driver.quit();
    }
    @Given("^I access webdriveruniversity contact us form$")
    public void i_access_webdriveruniversity_contact_us_form(){
        driver.get("http://www.webdriveruniversity.com/Contact-Us/contactus.html");
    }

    @When("^I enter a valid first name$")
    public void i_enter_a_valid_first_name(DataTable dataTable) throws InterruptedException {
        List<List<String>> data = dataTable.raw();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='first_name']")).sendKeys(data.get(0).get(0));
    }

    @When("^I enter a valid last name$")
    public void i_enter_a_valid_last_name(DataTable dataTable) throws InterruptedException {
        List<List<String>> data = dataTable.raw();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='last_name']")).sendKeys(data.get(0).get(0));

    }

    @And("^I enter a valid email address$")
    public void i_enter_a_valid_email_address(){
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='email']")).sendKeys("sample@gmail.com");
    }

    @And("^I enter comments$")
    public void i_enter_comments(DataTable dataTable){
        List<List<String >> data = dataTable.raw();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[name='message']")).sendKeys(data.get(0).get(0));
    }

    @When("^I click on the submit button$")
    public void i_click_on_the_submit_button(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
    }

    @Then("^The information should be successfully submitted via contact us form$")
    public void the_information_should_be_successfully_submitted_via_contact_us_form() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement thanksMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='contact_reply']/h1"));
        Assert.assertEquals("thankyouforyourmessage!",thanksMsg.getText().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[ ()0-9]",""));

    }

}
```

Main Runner class

```
package runners;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
        //feature files
        features = {"src/test/java/resources/features/"},
        //step files
        glue = {"WebDriverUniversity.stepDefinitions"},
        //It's about how the test result is shown in the console
        monochrome = true,
        // Doesn't execute the selenium code if true
        dryRun = false,
        //
        tags = {},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber","json:target/cucumber.json", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"}
)

public class MainRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

But when I run the contactUs.feature it states that the steps are undefined. I tried the different answers from the related stack overflow threads but no success yet.

**Project Structure**
[image]

**Run Configuration window**
[image]

**Run Results Window**
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible sample project as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . The files can be uploaded at https://uploads.jetbrains.com . (do not forget to specify the UploadID)

Comment: 2021_07_26_LZWzPGWmSDRwWTKv